# Wordpress custom theme I created is displaying all posts in categories and archives

Tags: php, wordpress

I just started playing around in WordPress, and created a theme for fun.

Everything is working properly except when I click on an archives month or category, the page I'm taken to displays all of the blog posts just like the main page, even though the slug is correct.

I've created an archive page and category page, replicating the main page since I want the design to be the same.

```
        <div class="recentBlogsWrapper">
            <h3><?php single_cat_title(); ?><?php get_the_archive_title(); ?> Category</h3>
            <div class="blogPostWrapper">
                <?php
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'posts_per_page' => 4,
                    );
                    $blogposts = new WP_Query($args);
                    while($blogposts->have_posts()) {
                        $blogposts->the_post();
                ?>
                <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" class="blogCard card">
                    <div class="blogHomeImgWrap">
                        <img class="blogPostImg" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url('get_the_ID'(),'full') ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="blogPadding">
                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                            <p><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></p>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <?php } wp_reset_query(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What am I missing with the query and how do I reference the link I just clicked on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have placed your code inside `archive.php` you shouldn't need to use a WP_Query (custom query), but just use the bog standard WordPress loop like this:

```
<div class="recentBlogsWrapper">
    <h3><?php single_cat_title(); ?><?php get_the_archive_title(); ?> Category</h3>
    <div class="blogPostWrapper">
        <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" class="blogCard card">
                <div class="blogHomeImgWrap">
                    <img class="blogPostImg" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'full' ) ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="blogPadding">
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <p><?php the_time( 'F j, Y' ); ?></p>
                </div>
            </a>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Explanation: by using the following code as an argument in your custom loop

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => 4,
);
```

You were asking WordPress to get all (any) posts. But in reality, you want to only grab posts in a certain category when you're on the category archive. Luckily for you, WordPress does all this for you, so by removing your custom query you should be good to go.